# React components not working in Customizer

Tags: react, applicationcustomizers

I am trying to use react components following [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-react-components-in-spfx-extension-application-customizer/) tutorial. But when I load the page I am getting a bunch of errors in chrome console complaining about invalid relative path in loading react and react-dom.

[image]

There is one more error after these errors:
[image]

Here is the code I am using to load tthe top place holder:

```
        if (this._topPlaceholder.domElement) {
            const element: React.ReactElement<IProps> = React.createElement(
              LeftNav,
              {}
            );
            ReactDom.render(undefined, this._topPlaceholder.domElement);
```

If I comment these lines , the error is gone. I checked the package json and node modules folder; react and reac-dom are added properly.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution [Here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/7050).

> Also, even if you use npm i react@16.9.0 version 16.14.0 will be
> installed because npm adds ^ to package version. I observed that
> Windows respects ^ sign, but Linux doesn't, so if you want to use
> React in SPFx, you should explicitly put 16.9.0 in package.

The issue is with version of react. 16.9.0 need to be specified explicitly.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility

Comment: I tried installing the exact version of react using `npm i react@16.9.0` but gave following error.Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@">=16.13.1 <18.0.0" from @microsoft/sp-core-library@1.17.3